# Is it possible to get the order referral code with the Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

If I use a buy it now link with a `ref` parameter like this:

```
https://my-site.myshopify.com/4589944918/checkouts/875eeab0d9826de7f83241e07d930339?ref=xxx34
```

then I can see `they used referral code xxx34` in the Shopify admin if I go to the order and then `view conversion details` > `view full session`.

However, this referral code value doesn't appear to show up in the order data that is returned by the `admin/orders.json` API endpoint.

Is there anyway to get the referral code using the Shopify API?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of small attributes an order has, you should check them all out:

- `landing_site_ref: "abc"`
- `reference: "fhwdgads"`
- `referring_site: "http://www.otherexample.com"`
- `landing_site: "http://www.example.com?source=abc"`

Probably the one you want is the first one in this small list.

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` value is stored in the `landing_site_ref` property.